# Reference properties cannot be set to deleted or discarded entities. Parameter name: value

Tags: c#, visual-studio-lightswitch

I have a problem with audit trial. Inserting and Updating works fine but when deleting I get error message.

I have found that a lot of us that used the same code, got the same error but no one found the solutions for it...

This is my code:

```
partial void HandoverSheetAogDesks_Deleted(HandoverSheetAogDesk entity)
    {
        var change = entity.AuditTrials.AddNew();
        change.ChangeType = "Deleted";

        change.Updated = DateTime.Now;
        change.ChangedBy = this.Application.User.FullName;

        var oldvals = "Deleted Values:";

        foreach (var prop in entity.Details.Properties.All().OfType<Microsoft.LightSwitch.Details.IEntityStorageProperty>())
        {
            if (prop.Name != "Id")
            {
                oldvals += string.Format("{0}{1}: {2}", Environment.NewLine, prop.Name, prop.Value);
            }
        }

        change.OriginalValues = oldvals;
    }
```

Error message is:

> Reference properties cannot be set to deleted or discarded entities. Parameter name: value

Comment: which line is throwing the error?

Comment: Well i dont know... I am able to run the project so it doesnt break when building it... Only when i try to delete an entry it shows that popup window with the error message... How can i troubleshoot it? Maybe it is because of table relationships?

Comment: put a try/catch in your code. Put a breakpoint in the catch clause and inspect the exception in run-time.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I didnt know how to do it since i am really a beginner in this (couple of days :)) but i found a great solution which here [link]http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/18ddf7/adding-record-from-one-table-to-another-table-in-lightswitch/